# Vertical scrollbar div when reduce browser window

Tags: css

I need put a vertical scroll in a div text when user reduce browser window and dont show all text but i can´t do.

```
#divCentraliza {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    left: 53%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -467px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-left: 70px;
    background-image: url(images/back_cont.png);
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kark8/

Comment: Add a jsFiddle to complete your example please.

Comment: Hi just added the code

Comment: you are not able to show scroll browser on resize or otherwise also?

Comment: It's difficult to see what the problem is from that fiddle. Please take out the code that's not relevant and explain better.

Comment: Hi. I can't reproduce your problem? Maybe an image? Sorry

Comment: Care to explain those? `left:53%;` and `margin-left: -467px;`